# SVG external link works with Chrome but not with Safari (WebKit)

Tags: php, google-chrome, safari, webkit, svg

I'm working on a php project that needs to display different SVG images depending on a variable. The image is displayed in a iFrame like this:

```
<iframe name="dispFrame" id="dispFrame" src="<?php echo $svgPath; ?>" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

where $svgPath is the path of the SVG file. This SVG file uses external references to another SVG to include some of its elements (it's a sort of library of pre-made elements).
Example:

```
<use xlink:href="../library.svg#bluebox"  x="200" y="280"/>
```

This works fine with Firefox and **Chrome**, but for some reason it doesn't in Safari. In Safari the main SVG file is displayed but without the element linked from the external library. 
I've read that used to be an **issue of WebKit** (on which both Chrome and Safari are based), but apparently WebKit says it is **solved** now. I'm not sure then why in Chrome works fine and in Safari doesn't. 
Any idea of what I can do to make it work on Safari as well?

Comment: 1. Your PHP code is completely irrelevant; only what it produces—what the browser sees—matters. 2. Changes to WebKit may take many months to show up in the latest Safari release, due to the pace of Apple's releases and their vetting process. Try a Nightly build to see if it's fixed but not yet released.

Comment: Thanks! - 1. I just thought that some context would make it easier to understand the issue. - 2. I know I can't really rely on Safari's updates. That's why I was wondering if there's an alternative way to use an external SVG reference that would work on Safari.